# composer install abhi1693/yii2-app-advanced-startup-kit error zelenin reposit not exits

Tags: yii2

estoy intentando instalar el paquete de https://github.com/abhi1693/yii2-app-advanced-startup-kit, le hago un `git clone` y al realizar un `composer update` se queda en actualizacion de la dependencia `zelenin/yii2-recaptcha-widget`, al parecer ya no esta disponible y no me permite continuar....

He borrado de la linea del `composer.json` la llamada de requerido de `zelenin`, pero me sigue apareciendo...

Answer (score 0):

El proyecto Yii2 Practical Application Advanced Template Startup-kit tiene reportado un [issue](https://github.com/abhi1693/yii2-app-advanced-startup-kit/issues/10) sobre esto mismo, ignoro si esto lo convierte en un recurso inestable.

Para poder actualizar los paquetes que persisten en composer puede limpiar el cache que este gaurda ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
$ composer clearcache packagename
```